# Could not cast value of type Swift._SwiftDeferredNSDictionary<Swift.String, Any> to KotlinMutableDictionary

Tags: swift, kotlin-native

I want to convert swift dictionary [String : Any] to KotlinMutableDictionary<NSString, NSString>. It doesn't allow to init with my swift dictionary.

```
    let kotlinDic = MykotlinClass.init(pages: <#T##KotlinMutableDictionary<NSString, NSString>#>)
// The class definitation
    
    let kotlinDic = MykotlinClass.init(pages: editableFiedlDic as! KotlinMutableDictionary<NSString, NSString>) 
// This is how I initialized
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast them directly (see [note](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/objc_interop.html#collections)), but you have to do something like that:

```swift
let swiftDic: [String : String] = [ "key1": "value1" , "key2": "value2" ]
let kotlinDic = KotlinMutableDictionary<NSString, NSString>.init(dictionary: swiftDic)
```

So in your case you should do

```swift
MykotlinClass.init(
    pages: KotlinMutableDictionary<NSString, NSString>.init(dictionary: editableFiedlDic)
)
```